# iOS UIViewController won't run in fullscreen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, fullscreen, prerequisites

iOS application (for example: just created from iOS template "Game") won't use fullscreen regardless you use storyboard or create all stuff at runtime. Also it doesn't matter that you changed the "Status bar style" (in project settings) or added any methods in UIViewController - it won't help.

Answer (score 0):

iOS application can't use fullscreen without filled "Launch screen file" (in project setting -> General).

[image] [image]

[image]